# Rollback privileges

Tags: discussion, editing, moderation

Is everyone regardless of reputation able to rollback edits? It seems we have an influx of users spamming with questionable content, to say the least, and it would seem they are able to rollback edits made by honorable members of the community.

I suspect the spammers will not be accounts with great amount of rep, so how come they are allowed to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any user can rollback edits made to their own posts.

Beyond that, I think that only users with the "edit" ability can roll back edits to other users' posts.

This is one reason that editing objectionable content isn't a recommended solution, but rather reporting it as "spam" or "abusive". Both of those will lead quickly to deletion, and suspending or banning the author.